# What's the equivalent of Perl's backticks in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, perl, shell-exec, backticks

In Perl you can do something like

```
perl -E'my $date = `date`; say $date'
```

This is a terse way to run a command synchronously and set the variable to STDOUT. In Node, how can I quickly run a command to capture the stdout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [.execSync](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options) with an explicit encoding.. In the shortest form (with whitespace),

```
var date = require('child_process').execSync('date', {encoding: 'utf8'} )
console.log(date);
```

Comment: I get Object #<Object> has no method 'execSync' when trying to run this, any idea?

Comment: Though to be more equivalent to Perl (which doesn't use utf8 by default), use the 'binary' encoding.

Comment: This is so much better than the other answers for executing commands in node.